# Use Meteor accounts packages outside a Meteor app

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have an old Meteor application that is no longer developed/supported, it has a number of users. I have a new app to replace it.

In my new Express app, I have a login handler that can accept a username+password.

How can I make calls like `Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, callback)` when I am not actually in a meteor app. There are many references in the docs to the `accounts-password` package, but this is not an npm package in itself.

How can I install the required packages outside the meteor CLI? I'm just in a regular npm express app.

Comment: You will actually have to use another implementation, since `accounts-password` is a Meteor specific implementation of the oauth2 workflow that is tightly bound to a DDP connection. There are however good npm packages like passport that allow you to solve this issue in node+express. Or do you want to provide your users a login with their Meteor app's accoutn, something like an SSO?